# Cannot upload vector to fragment shader in Stage3D

Tags: flash, stage3d, agal

I am trying to upload a vector to the shader but it's not working and I can found why.

Here is the code:

```
mov ft0.rgb, fc0.rgbb
tex ft1, v1.rggg, fs0 <2d, linear, nomip, repeat>
mov ft0.a, ft1.aaaa
mov oc, ft0
```

Where fc0 is the vector I am trying to upload:

With this function I call before drawTriangles and present:

```
Engine.context.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 0, Vector.<Number>([value1, value2, value3]));
```

I've debugged the scene with [Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) and apparently fc0 has no value.

If I substitue the last ft0 for ft1 it works since I am rendering only the texture.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector that you upload needs to have at least 4 elements in it.

See [the description of the data parameter on this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3D.html#setProgramConstantsFromVector%28%29).